# Currrently Javascript API avalaible to all Excel versions

Tags: office-scripts

Please, is there a way to access the currently javascript API available independently of which Excel version I have??? At the moment only E3 or E5 licenses have this access and the ScriptLab still works with an older API. Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you please share an API example that cannot run in script lab? have you try this API in Excel online with script lab?

Comment: Also, is this in relation to Office Scripts (Recording and scripting in Excel Online) or Add-ins? Please remove office-scripts tag if it is in relation to add-ins (or script lab)

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy My question is about the Office Scripts(Recording and Scripting in Excel Online), I apologyse to add the office-js and office-addins tags!

Comment: @RaymondLu I try run the script: `function main(workbook: ExcelScript.Workbook) {let shName = workbook.getActiveWorksheet();}` But within Script lab, this peace of script doesn't run! The script lab don't recognize the ExcelScript part, for example and the method getActiveWorksheet... On the other hand the script lab run without a problem the peace of code: `async function main(context: Excel.RequestContext){let shName = context.workbook.worksheets.getItem("Sheet1");}`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to Microsoft: *"The async model can only be used with scripts created before the implementation of the current API model. Scripts are permanently locked to the API model they have upon creation. This also means that if you want to convert an old script to the new model, you must create a brand new script. We recommend you update your old scripts to the new model when making changes, since the current model is easier to use. The Converting async scripts to the current model section has advice on how to make this transition."*
Script Lab and Office Scripts might feel the same, but they are certainly different. You can't run any code in both Office Scripts and Script Lab. They require different parameters. [Support older Office Scripts that use the async APIs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/scripts/develop/excel-async-model)

Comment: +1. Script Lab is more of a playgroud for add-in development. It uses the async Excel APIs suitable for add-ins. Office Scripts now uses a much simpler model that is optimized for end user automation and yet offers all the API capabilities.

Comment: @SudhiRamamurthy Thank you and its clear for me now! I know that office script is only run in te browser. Is that anything on going project to make office script available on Excel desktop? By using node.js perhaps to interpreter the office script code... I don't know is it even possible. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Thanks @Ethan for the answer!

Comment: There is investigation underway for desktop support - but still under the framework of Office Scripts UI experience. The node.js/server side support is not in the plan at the moment -- thought one can run the scripts through run-script action under Excel within Power Automation.